# iPad: Force iPad Updates

Tags: iphone, ipad, updates

I've been developing an application for our client and they are requesting that we add in compulsory updates for their application. The app allows sales-team members to showcase their product and they are worried that if a product gets re-called then the sales-team must reflect this in the app immediately or else there could be legal implications for the company. How feasible is this to implement? Are there any examples of this in use?

Cheers for the help guys,

Dan

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[iPhone\] Force user to update app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604503/iphone-force-user-to-update-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you could do this is to get the app to call the server and ask for the latest version number. If it's different then stop the app and tell the user to upgrade. However, this won't work if they start the app without a network connection :)

I also don't know if this will be allowed by Apple?

A better way to do it is for the app to download a list of products each time it runs (cahcing it incse it starts with no connection of course!) so that the products in the app are always up to date and the users never need to upgrade at all.

Comment: I like your suggestion, I dont think we could have such an overhaul of the structure as this before the deadline but it's definitely something to feed back to the client. Cheers!

Comment: Any chance you have some more information about whether this is allowed by Apple or not?

Comment: Sorry, if I knew any more it would be in my answer ;)

Comment: @Daniel - If this is an application just being used by an in-the-field sales force, why aren't they just becoming members of the iOS Developer Enterprise Program?  They could distribute this without relying on the App Store and approval then.